# Swift is flagging the use of deprecated functions as errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have a private cocoapod that I've built. It's written in Obj-C. I had some old APIs in my library, that I wanted to mark as deprecated, mainly as a reminder to my team that they should start using some newer APIs.

So I have a routine, in my ObjC library, that looks like this:

```
-(void) myOldRoutine DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use myNewRoutine instead");
```

In my client app, I have both ObjC and Swift files. If I call "myOldRoutine" in my ".m" file, I just get a compiler warning.

But if I make the exact same call, in Swift, I get an error. The error message is identical to the warning message, except it's an error, and halts compilation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is weird. So you don't waste time I suggest you stop using deprecated methods and upgrade your project.

Comment: Haha. Well, they're routines that I flagged as deprecated myself, just to get my own apps to eventually migrate to the new routines. I was just trying to mark it as notation, so I would have an easy way to see when I'm using older APIs.

Comment: Do you have the "Treat Warnings As Errors" checkbox set in your Project or Target settings?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - good question. No, that would cause big problems, as I use other pods, and they have warnings, too. And I don't know how that flag would be set for only Swift and not for ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

Swift has an own setting that controls if warnings are errors. It's named `SWIFT_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS`.  Whereas the setting which controls this for C/Obj-C/C++ is named `GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS`. If the first one is set, deprecations result in warnings everywhere but Swift where they are errors.

Answer (score -3):

Just replace your deprecated routine: 
`-(void) myOldRoutine DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("Use myNewRoutine instead");` 
with the "#warning - your comment".